# File path to work on android studio and also on intllij

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, plugins, jar

How can get my txt file path in order to work on intellij and as well on android studio after a jar file is generated and then imported in android studio

In this exemple it does work on intellij when i test it after jar file is generated, but when i import this jar file in android studio it says FileNotFoundExceptions

Bellow is the code that works on intellij but not on android studio

```
File outputFile = new File("C://Users//acg//IdeaProjects//Xml2Pojo//src//" + packageName + "//" + className + ".txt");
```

Comment: Please, is there someone to help, i really appreciate it

Comment: Actualy i am developing a plugin for android studio in intellij that need to read and write data to text file, but i can get it how to define path in order to work on android studio

Comment: Don't know if this is the issue, but `//` is redundant and could be just `/`.  You need to double only when using `\\\` to represent a single backslash.

Comment: I dont think this can fix this cause it actualy works on intellij but not in android studio

Comment: Does it work on AS if you manually input full file path?

Comment: No it still does not work, i think its because AS is unable to read or access file from jar